# 'projectile-global-mode' function is void at the startup, why?

Tags: init-file, helm, projectile

I am addicted to helm-projectile, unfortunately after a recent update, all of a sudden I get the warning message at Emacs start-up that the function `projectile-global-mode` is void. Before that, everything was working perfectly fine.

**related init.el**

```
(require 'package) ; only once in init.el
(package-initialize) ; only once in init.el
(require 'helm) ; install package
(require 'helm-config)
(helm-mode 1)
(setq exec-path (add-to-list 'exec-path "C:/Program Files/Gow/bin"))
(setenv "PATH" (concat "C:\\Program Files\\Gow\\bin;" (getenv "PATH")))
(projectile-global-mode)        
(setq projectile-completion-system 'helm)
(helm-projectile-on)
(setq projectile-indexing-method 'alien) 
(setq projectile-switch-project-action 'projectile-dired)
(setq projectile-enable-caching t)
```

I tried to change it to:

```
(projectile-global-mode +1)
```

but no success.

I tried to search for this function `projectile-global-mode` but could not find it when I do `C-h f` and could not even find it in the `helm-projectile.el` file where supposed to be AFAIK. So what am I missing?

**Notes**
- Windows 7 machine 32bit
- Emacs version 24.4.1
- all packages were updated from MELPA

Comment: You should try deleting projectile and helm-projectile then install it again. Sometimes it's just bad installation.

Comment: Great! I just deleted them and re-installed them and worked fine like before. Yet another Emacs housekeeping trick to learn. Feel free to upgrade it to an answer. I wouldn't find any easier solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a problem of bad installation. Just remove and install, and it will work again.